# jquery check if there is browser supporter <meter> tag

Tags: jquery

I've been working through a text book for css3 and there is some jquery to check for browser support for the meter tag.

The code is a follows.

```
varnoMeterSupport = function(){ 
    return(document.createElement('meter').max === undefined); 
}
```

I partially understand this, in that when the doc loads it creates a meter tag. But doesn't it asign it's max value as undefined Rather than returning a boolean value for if the items has a maximum value?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This code is checking to see if the element that was created has a `max` property. If it doesn't then the function will return false.

Comment: Could you expand on this please? Is it the exactly equal to part that does this? Iwan expecting an if statement or loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see jQuery here, it is plain vanilla javascript.

Code you pasted is a short version of this:

```
varnoMeterSupport = function() {
    // Create "meter" element
    var meterElement = document.createElement('meter');

    // If meterElement does not have "max" attribute 
    // (it is equal to undefined) means browser does not
    // support this feature.
    if (meterElement.max === undefined) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Triple "equal sign" (===) is used to compare something not to assign value to variable.